# javascript call function extern

Tags: javascript, function

I have a file with code  of these functions

stickem.js:

```
 ;(function($, window, document, undefined) {

    var Stickem = function(elem, options) {
        this.elem = elem;
        this.$elem = $(elem);
        this.options = options;
        this.metadata = this.$elem.data("stickem-options");
        this.$win = $(window);
    };

    Stickem.prototype = {
        defaults: {
            item: '.stickem',
            container: '.stickem-container',
            stickClass: 'stickit',
            endStickClass: 'stickit-end',
            offset: 0,
            start: 0,
            onStick: null,
            onUnstick: null
        },


    bindEvents: function() {
            var _self = this;


            _self.$win.on('scroll.stickem', $.proxy(_self.handleScroll, _self));


        _self.$win.on('resize.stickem', $.proxy(_self.handleResize, _self));
            },

handleResize: function() {
            var _self = this;

            _self.getItems();
            _self.setWindowHeight();
            console.log('fdf');
    },


.....  ....
```

now I want to call in my another js file "tests.js" this function"handleResize" 
from "stickem.js"  how can I do?

Thank you for Help

Comment: You're not exposing `Stickem` to the outside, so that will be challenging.

Answer (score 0):

You can set any functions you want to use in other files as a variable on window. Eg.

```
window.Stickem = Stickem;
```

in your stickem.js.

You will also need to make sure the order of your script tags is correct (ie that the file above is at the top).

NOTE: if your javascript is currently in your html files you should move it out into external js files. Eg.

```
<script src="stickem.js"></script>
<script src="tests.js"></script>
```

Comment: these files are separated in external js files